# Password Not Getting Updated CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to reset the password but it doesn't update. Can someone fix this? I am getting an error message saying I'm not submitting enough non-code so this is filler.

This is reset.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'reset')); ?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->input('password',array("type"=>"password","name"=>"data[User][password]"));
echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm',array("type"=>"password","name"=>"data[User][password_confirm]"));

echo $this->Form->submit();

echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

This is the reset method in UsersController.php

```
function reset($token=null){
        //$this->layout="Login";
        $this->User->recursive=-1;
        if(!empty($token)){
            $u=$this->User->findBytokenhash($token);
            if($u){
                $this->User->id=$u['User']['id'];
                if(!empty($this->data)){
                    $this->User->data=$this->data;
                    $this->User->data['User']['username']=$u['User']['username'];
                    $new_hash=sha1($u['User']['username'].rand(0,100));//created token
                    $this->User->data['User']['tokenhash']=$new_hash;
                    if($this->User->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('password','password_confirm')))){
                        if($this->User->save($this->User->data))
                        {
                            $this->Session->setFlash('Password Has been Updated');
                            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        $this->set('errors',$this->User->invalidFields());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Token Corrupted,Please Retry.the reset link work only for once.');
            }
        }

        else{
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's more to reset.ctp that I forgot to add:

Comment: <p>Click on the link below to Reset Your Password </p><br/>

<a href="<?php echo $this->Session->read('ms'); ?>">Click here to Reset Your Password</a><br/>

<pre>or Visit this Link</pre><br/>

<p><a href="<?php echo $this->Session->read('ms'); ?>"><?php echo $this->Session->read('ms'); ?></a></p>

Comment: I'm using CakePHP version 2.2.2.

Comment: I set a redirect after the line $this->set('errors',$this->User->invalidFields()); and it goes there so I know that it reaches that part of the code. However, no error messages print. I set Configure::write(‘debug’, 2); in core.php but it still doesn’t print any errors.

Comment: It prints out "Password has been updated" now and redirects to the login page but the password doesn't actually get changed.

Comment: The reason it didn't redirect to the right page before is that my User model had faulty validation rules.

Comment: I get the error Undefined index: password when I change if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) to if($this->User->saveField('password',$this->request->data['U‌​ser']['password']))

Comment: When I put debug($this->request->data['User']); in my UsersController and then look at the data returned by the submitted form it only shows password_confirm and not password.

Comment: You have way to much (dangerous) logic in the controller here. I highly recommend reading [this](https://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) and maybe even using the Passwordable behavior to use hashing here more secure and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my reset.ctp and the password got updated: echo $this->Form->input('password');

Comment: Everything works now but when I add validation rules to my User model the password value becomes a much longer string than what I've typed in.